# Suggestions regarding how to make web-service

Tags: android, database, web-services

I am starting with a new app i which i will be needing web services.All the data will be coming from the data base.My database will look something like this

```
Id
Name(Birds Name)
Description
Date
Image for that Name
```

Now i want to give all the values to user in json array.But i am confused on few points

1. How will i send images in json array
2. Is it correct to store Images in Database?
3. There may be 3-5 images for a particular name,so do i create a different table for images with foreign key??

P.S-Also it would be grateful if some one can give me link on how to make a web-service which i can consume in my android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:-

1. To send images in JSON Array, you need to convert your images into BASE64 first and then add it in your JSON Array object. This BASE64 type can be received on the webserver and a reverse operation could be performed to get the actual image.
2. NO. Images are never stored in Database. Rather store their corresponding path. Its always better to save images on the external storage.
3. Yes. You can create a separate table, but to store the path of images, not the images itself. You can then use foreign key to acces the images path and then the images respectively.

Comment: Thankyou Sir.If i entered image path in my database then how can i download the images???

Comment: why not???
Your images can have a specific URL...you can hit it to download them

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the techno, I use [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) + [Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/). A good choice, because endpoints generate with Maven the model for the Android app based on your AppEngine datastore.